# How to import an report from power bi report builder to Power BI nomal?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, reportbuilder3.0

I created a paginated report in the power Bi report builder. However, when I try to import this report as a visual into power bi desktop, it doesn't let me "activate" the parameters. What can it be?